# create cache for measure with a condition

Tags: ssas, mdx

How to create cache for the query where the measure has a condition, is there any other better way to do it?

Every time the results comes back in 6 seconds, I want to make it less than 2 seconds

```
    WITH MEMBER TotalPaidHigh AS SUM   
(   
Filter (    
     {    
        [Employee].[EmployeeID].Members},   
        [Measures].[Score] <= 4 AND    
           [Measures].[Score] >= 1   
            }   
        ),   
    [Measures].[PaidAmount]    
)
MEMBER TotalPaidLow AS   
(
    ([Measures].[PaidAmount]) - (TotalPaidHigh)   
)   
SELECT   
{    
    TotalPaidHigh, TotalPaidLow   
} ON 0   
FROM     
    [Cube]     
WHERE   
(      
  {   
        [Date].[Month].&[April 2011],   
    [Date].[Month].&[May 2011],    
    [Date].[Month].&[June 2011]    
  }    
  ,[Geography].[State].&[NY]    
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to define PaidHigh as an additional physical measure in the cube. Then the pre-aggregated values of that measure would be cached by Analysis Services, and it would only have to do the final calculation on the results of teh aggregations - which is fast.